# Audit.Net:Setup().ForContext<MyContext>() results in no entities being mapped

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration, audit.net

Configuring Audit.EntityFramework with the below configuration (part of Audit.Net) does not result in the proper mapping of entities. 
    `Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup().ForContext<AuditAudiCCPContext>().UseOptOut();`

The method

```
public override object InsertEvent(AuditEvent auditEvent)
```

of `EntityFrameworkDataProvider.cs` returns without any exception because it is unable to find the mapped entity.
Line 96 of `EntityFrameworkDataProvider.cs`:

```
var mappedType = _auditTypeMapper?.Invoke(type, entry);
```

which attempts to map the entity to the audited entity fails to produce any result.

I tried the following other configurations

a.

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
        .ForContext<AuditAudiCCPContext>(config => config
         .ForEntity<SubjectInfo>(_=>_.Ignore(e=>e.Ticket).Ignore(e=>e.LevelSubjectMap))
        .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"))
        .UseOptIn();
```

b. The suggestions in this post -[How do I target another database with Audit.Net - Audit.EntityFramework.Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780463/how-do-i-target-another-database-with-audit-net-audit-entityframework-core)

c. I am unable to use the method `UseEntityFramework` on `Setup()` because it is unavailable.

It should create an entry in the audit database table, but that does not happen. There are no exceptions either.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically missing to configure the [EntityFramework Data Provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#entity-framework-data-provider).

You must call the `.UseEntityFramework()` extension method to configure the mapping between your data entities and your audit entities, for example:

```
using Audit.Core;

Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(_ => _
        .AuditTypeExplicitMapper(map => map
            .Map<SubjectInfo, SubjectInfo_Audit>()
            .Map<xxxx, xxxx_Audit>()));
```

Also [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#ef-provider-configuration-examples) some configuration examples.